# DDD, Can aggregate handle an event from another aggregate?

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

Is it right to handle an event in a aggregate published from another aggregate ? Or a domain should only handle commands ?

In my case, I have an application which manages settings. I have an aggregate for application and an aggregate for applicationGroup. When I want to create a settings for a specific group of applications, then the command is handled by my applicationGroup, then the applicationGroup publish an event GroupSettingsCreated, but does DDD say we can handle this event directly in my ApplicationAggregate ? Or should I handle this event in an event handler ,map it into a command then send it to my ApplicationAggregate ?

Thanks

John

Comment: I see nothing wrong with that. For example, in my model - when contract is signed, payment plan knows that it should re-plan itself. This of course requires association to figure out which plan should respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're tempted to handle one aggregate's event inside another aggregate, the handler should be a child of the aggregate generating the event.

In other words, in this [bounded context](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/91s), `Application` should be a child of `ApplicationGroup` and `ApplicationGroup.CreateSettings()` should propagate settings to its child applications.

Another way to think of this: an "application group" might not be a true aggregate - but rather a convenience provided by the user interface.

Comment: Interesting, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

John, I don't know of anything in DDD that speaks to your question. This is really a question of [Event Driven Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture) (EDA) and [Command Query Responsibility Segregation](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) (CQRS).

To give more specific advice, I'd like to know what roles the application and applicationGroup entities play. BTW, they sound more like application/infrastructure concepts than domain concepts.

In general, I use commands where the next action is logically pushed from the source (the next action is a necessary next step). I use events when the action in question is logically a reaction to the upstream behavior (the upstream code is unaware of this reaction to what just happened).

Comment: hi @Eric Farr, to give you more precision about my scenario, when attaching an "application" to an "application group", the
"application group" should send all the current "settings" to the
"application". As to say, the Application group aggregate publish an event handled by application aggregate which in turn publish event for creating the settings. The problem with this interaction is that an event trigger another event and as you said, it's a the role of the command to send event.

Comment: What I've done so far, it's to map the event from "application group" aggregate into a command, then send it to "application" aggregate. The amount of glue code needed (event => mapping =>
command) makes me think that something is wrong there. I'm gonna try @Jeff Sternal solution

Comment: @John, that makes sense. I was suspicious of those two being separate roots, but it was hard to say without knowing more. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks to you for asking for more clarifications. I hasn't provided enough information in my first post. Your intervention was helpful, it make me think more about what details are wrong in my scenario :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do it in this way cause it will lead to a messy code. Instead, use [sagas](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/04/20/saga-persistence-and-event-driven-architectures/) for am orchestration. [Here is](http://vimeo.com/20839681) also good video from Andreas Öhlund on sagas in NServiceBus.

Comment: Yes, I agree that it'd be a messy code. As far as I know, sagas are used when we need a temporal workflow ? But thanks for the link, I'll take a look.

Comment: Sagas are not only for workflow. Sagas is the main tool for orchestration (especially between bounded contexts)- they consume events and produce commands.